# C++ Pass Template class definition to a Macro in compile time

Tags: c++, dynamic, macros

I have to use a function in library with variable parameters (createObject), the general usage is:

```
Class Point 
{
public: 
    Point() {};
    int x;
    int y;
    const char* name;
}

int main() 
{
    Point p;
    createObject("%d",p.x,"%f",p.y,"%d",1,"%s",p.name);
}
```

Now i want to generalize usage of this function with Macro and Template, like this:

```
#define PARAM_Matrix(obj) "%d",obj.m,"%d",obj.n,"%d %d",obj[0][0],"%d %d",obj[0][1],"%d %d",obj[0][2]
#define PARAM_Person(obj) "%d",obj.age,"%s",obj.name
#define PARAM_Point(obj) "%d",obj.x,"%f",obj.y,"%d",1,"%s",obj.name
#define MAKE_PARAM(className,obj) PARAM_##className(obj)

class Person;
class Matrix; 
class Point 
{
public: 
    Point() {};
    int x;
    int y;
    const char* name;
}

template<typename T> createGeneralize(T t)
{
    return createObject(MAKE_PARAM(T,t));
}

int main()
{
   Person per;
   Matrix m;
   Point p;

   createGeneralize<Person>(per);
   createGeneralize<Matrix>(m);
   createGeneralize<Point>(p);
}
```

I expected that in `createGeneralize()` the C++ compiler expanding the macro to `MAKE_PARAM(Point,t)` (or MAKE_PARAM(Matrix,t)...). However, it is not the case, it always expands to `MAKE_PARAM(T)`.

Comment: What is the problem with `DYNAMIC_CLASS(T)`, which eventually *preprocesses* to `T u,v;u=v;`? Its still valid C++ (though odd). You asked for solving "my problem" but didn't expand on what the problem *is* ? Does your code not *run* (assuming you fixed `Class` to be `class` and terminated the class with a proper `;`) ?

Comment: Suppose you add a few more function calls: `doMore(3);doMore(4.5);doMore("abc");` What do you want your macro to expand to?

Comment: Thanks you, I editted my question to clear my purpose

Comment: There is one macro call, and it is expanded once. You cannot have one macro call to expand to this and that and yet another thing.

Comment: No, I've already sucessfully call one macro from another macro. If I call MAKE_PARAM(Point,t), the result is ok. But the problem is the C++ compiler can't not translate from T to Point (or Person,Matrix)

Comment: If the compiler cannot translate, perhaps you can? Show the translated file you want to get.

Comment: My expected translated file: 

createGeneralize(per); translated to return createObject(MAKE_PARAM(Point,per))

createGeneralize(m); translated to return createObject(MAKE_PARAM(Matrix,m));

It's the same for createGeneralize(p);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73842/discussion-between-ronaldinho-and-n-m).

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is not feasible because the preprocessor macros are converted to text before actual compiling. while the template arguments are substituted during compilation. so you get something like:

```
doMore (Point p)
{
    T u, v; u = v;
}
```

i suggest just use templates.

Comment: That's why I have to ask you for the answer. Template didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of macro, you may use template:

```
auto as_tuple(const Person& obj) { return std::make_tuple("%d", obj.age, "%s", obj.name); }
auto as_tuple(const Matrix& obj) { return std::make_tuple("%d", obj.m,"%d",obj.n,"%d %d",obj.obj[0][0],"%d %d",obj.obj[0][1],"%d %d",obj.obj[0][2]); }
auto as_tuple(const Point& obj) { return std::make_tuple("%d", obj.x,"%f",obj.y,"%d",1,"%s",obj.name); }

template<typename Tuple, std::size_t...Is>
void createGeneralize(const Tuple& t, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    return createObject(std::get<Is>(t)...);
}

template<typename T> void createGeneralize(const T& t)
{
    const auto& tuple = as_tuple(t);
    return createGeneralize(tuple, std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<std::decay_t<decltype(tuple)>>::value>());
}
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/v1OQ2v)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm trying to compile your code (in liveexample) but I got error: 
         ‘std::index_sequence’ has not been declared
         ‘make_index_sequence’ is not a member of ‘std’.

Did you use C++11 or higher

Comment: I use C++14, but code can be ported to c++11 with some effort.